# how to expand child node as vertically - D3 chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm using below d3 v3 for Employees Hierarchy Chart

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlEiP.png)

[Example](https://gist.github.com/bumbeishvili/dbc0beff4baf64674b0f05b94cb4462e?permalink_comment_id=3366404)

now, the problem is when we have too many child nodes it expands horizontally, making the view too long

let's say the parent node has 19 child nodes

[too many nodes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMeHa.png)

can we expand the child node vertically?

like this [vertical if possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Dhl.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, @Emma?